# Nodejs mongoose Mass/Batch update from file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

So i have a csv file containing my information, i need to do a mass `add/update`

```
exports.add_questions_from_file = function (file_path, surveyid, callback)
{
    var U = [{}];
    fs.readFile(file_path, 'utf8', function(err, data){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        callback(err,null);
    }else{
        console.log(data);
        d = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        for (x=0;x <d.length;x++)
        {
            line = d[x].split(',');
            if (line[0] == "") {return};
            RQuestion.add_by_line (line,function (err, question)
            {
                    U.push({id:question.id});
                    console.log(U);
            });
        }   
    }

    }); 
    Survey.update({_id:surveyid},{$push:{"SurveyQuestions":U}},function (err,numAffected, rawResponse) {
                console.log(rawResponse);
                 RET = {"module":"survey","operation": "add", "status":"OK"};
                callback(RET);
    });
};
```

But even though im using callback functions the update seems to happen with the same object always, even the `console.log` here

```
U.push({id:question.id});
console.log(U);
```

returns the same object (even that all the other were created)

Im doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues.

First for:

```
if (line[0] == "") {return};
```

Don't you mean to use a break or continue instead? Otherwise the entire function will quit if there is a blank line anywhere in the file. This is very important because Survey.update won't get called either.

Second: I assumed that RQuestion.add_by_line and Survey.update are doing something async like updating a database. Your code needs to be restructured to wait for those async items to complete before moving on to the next step. I'd recommend an npm package named [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) for that.

```
fs.readFile(file_path, 'utf8', function(err, data){
 if (err){
     console.log(err);
     callback(err,null);
 }else{
    d = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);

    async.map(d, function(line, callback) {
        //this function is called for each line
       add_by_line (line,function (err, question)
       {
         callback(err,{id:question.id});
       });
    }, function(err, results) {
        //this function is called when all of the items are done
        console.log("done with async");
        console.dir(results);
        Survey.update({_id:surveyid},{$push:{"SurveyQuestions":results},function (err,numAffected, rawResponse) {
                console.log(rawResponse);
                RET = {"module":"survey","operation": "add", "status":"OK"};
                callback(RET);
        });

    });

 }
});
```